# My laptop behavies weird until I press shift

Tags: laptop, keyboard

Firstly on booting I got message that my password is wrong although I havent even had a chance to physically to type something.I can press ok to type again,but it leaves me the same message that my password is wrong no matter how much time I press without even letting me each time to type password.When I press shift everything become normal.That lasts for about 5 minutes and then my computer starts openning everything I click on in new windowa.Mouse starts selecting everything when I try to select something and scroll on mouse stop working.Also my upper and lower letter switch,e.g. my caps lock indicator is turned on but it keeps typing small letters.
Sometimes it doesnt stop with pressing left shift,so I have to press right shift.
I had in the past problem with filter keys,no matter if I disable it or not ,they keep turning by themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your <kbd>Shift</kbd> button is broken:

- Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> temporarily eases the issue
- Typing "*incorrect*" passwords (i.e: incorrect case is used because <kbd>Shift</kbd> is "*pressed*")
- Typing lowercase with caps lock on (i.e: incorrect case is used because <kbd>Shift</kbd> is "*pressed*")
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> will open new windows / select multiple items
- Filter keys keep turning on (they are turned on by holding <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> for 8 seconds)

Have you recently spilled something on it, or is the key physically damaged?

You could look for a replacement keyboard for your laptop.

Comment: You have great reasoning.I would give you best answer if it was possible,but it isnt since I am new user.Now all makes sense.My mom spilled hot soup 3 years ago on it.